# Remote access error to local website (Openserver)

Tags: server, windows-10, admin, remote-access

I have a website my-test.loc which is successfully working locally OpenServer.

**OpenServer settings:**

- Modules: Apache_2.4-PHP_8.0-8.1+Nginx_1.23.
- Domains - Domain name: "my-test.loc"
- Domains - Domain folder: "\my-test\public"
- Aliases - Source Domain: "192.168.1.146"
- Aliases - Target Domain: "my-test.loc"
- Server - Http: 80
- Server - Https: 443
- Server - Backend: 8080
- Server - Protect web server from external access: off

**Router settings (Archer AX1500 Wi-Fi 6 Router):**

- Nat forwarding - IP: 192.168.1.146
- Nat forwarding - External port: 80
- Nat forwarding - Internal port: 80
- Nat forwarding - Protocol: TCP
- Nat forwarding - State: On

**Local machine settings:**

- Machine IP: 192.168.1.146.
- OS: Windows 10.
- Windows Defender - "inbound rules": ports 80, 8080, 3000 are allowed for: domain,public,private
- Eset NOD firewall is totally turned off.
- Say, my external ip is: 90.90.90.90.
- Connection to the internet: Wi-fi.
- Wi-fi connection - settings: both IPv4 and IPv6 are turned on (but also I've tried turn off IPv6 without reboot PC).
- Hosts file contains automatically added rows: 1) 192.168.1.146 my-test.loc and 2) 192.168.1.146 my-test.

**Local access:**
It works good by host and local machine IP:

- https://my-test.loc/
- http://192.168.1.146/

**Remote access:**
I get an error when I try get access by external IP http://90.90.90.90/

```
How did you get here? To redirect requests for an IP address to the domain you need, create an alias in the program settings.
```

I get another error when I turn off Openserver:

```
This site can’t be reached.
```

So, looks like remote access already communicate with OpenServer. But I checked all available Openserver logs, I dont see requests to Apache, nginx. Nothing.

**Question:**
Do you have idea why access to the local site still not working?